# Endogeneity for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, simulation, endogeneity

I would like to construct a setup where there is endogeneity between a binary  independent variable and (in the latent formulation) the logistic noise. The set up has to be easy to simulate and correlation between the noise and the independent variable must be such that it can be controlled by the user. So to sum up this would give something like :

$$Y^*=\beta.X+X_e+\mathcal{L}$$

where the binary observation dependent variable $Y=1_{[Y^*>0]}$, 
the independent variables $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ is anything you like as long as it easy to simulate, and $X_e$ is binary (coded 0 1 for example) and such that :
$$Corr(X_e,\mathcal{L})=\frac{Cov(X_e,\mathcal{L})\pi}{\sigma(X_e).\sqrt{3}}=\frac{Cov(X_e,\mathcal{L})\pi}{\sqrt{3.p_e.(1-p_e)}}=\rho\in (-1,1)$$

As a logistic random variable has variance $\frac{\pi^2}{3}$ and centered, due to the fact that $\mathbb{E}[X_e]=p_e, \operatorname{Var}[X_e]=p_e.(1-p_e)$ as it is a Bernoulli variable when viewed in a standalone manner.

I hope I am clear enough the problem is trickier as I first thought please comment if additional information is needed.

Comment: Addenda : Taking $X_e=1_{\{\mathcal{L}>a\}}$ or $X_e=1_{\{\mathcal{L}<a\}}$gives closed form solution formula unfortunately it is not possible to get every value of $\rho$. Numerical experiment shows that you can roughly get $\rho \in (-0.8,0.8)$. Best regards

Comment: Moreover after thinking things a little more through, I believe that as a matter of fact a binary random variable cannot be correlated to a logistic random variable over those thresholds. I don't have a full rigorous mathematical proof, only a heuristic argument which makes intuitively sense. I will post later my full answer. Best regards